# Combine Rows with Duplicate value, SUM non-duplicate values

Tags: powershell

I have a data set of devices, with varying counts. The device names and types will always be duplicates of eachother, but the counts will vary. The data is pulled from multiple SQL queries and I drop it into a PSObject

The resulting data looks like this:

[image]

What I need is to SUM the individual count columns, for the above example, giving me the below output:

[image]

Doing something like `Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique` doesn't help with summing the count rows, and removing the `unique` parameter, I can't figure out how to work the `Group-Object` that I think I need to separate the rows and sum them. The resultant group is just a huge line of the same data, since devices have upwards of 20 counts (Count1, Count2... Count19, Count20...)

Any help to point me down the right track here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may be easier to do by getting the source data directly rather than processing a modified form.

Comment: You should try to write some of the code. We are not a professional code writing service

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I did try that first, the problem I ran into there is that I'm pulling the data from multiple databases hosted on multiple servers, and the only way I could get the data to combine appropriately was creating an object to store it in. I've been contemplating creating a temp table in my database to store the info in, and do the aggregate in SQL, but if at all possible I'd prefer to keep the actual logic in the PowerShell script since going back and forth can get messy.

Comment: @KolobCanyon I did try to write "some": of the code, in fact I wrote all of it, but I'm stuck on doing the aggregate function, which is why I posted here. I'm asking for help in what direction to take, not for somebody to write it for me. I don't even know if the `Sort-Object` and `Group-Object` functions are the right track, or the best track to take in this. Do you have any suggestions that might be helpful? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$SQL = ConvertFrom-CSV @"
Name,Type,Count1,Count2,Count3
Device1,Type1,0,12,0
Device1,Type1,0,5,0
Device1,Type1,1,0,0
Device1,Type1,0,0,3
Device2,Type2,5,0,0
Device2,Type2,1,0,0
Device3,Type2,0,5,0
Device3,Type2,0,1,1
Device3,Type2,1,1,2
"@


$SQL | Group-Object Name | ForEach {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $_.Name
        Type = $_.Group[0].Type
        Count1 = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Count1 -Sum).Sum
        Count2 = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Count2 -Sum).Sum
        Count3 = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Count3 -Sum).Sum
    }
} | Format-Table
```

Comment: You. Are. Awesome! I didn't know that the `Group` would retain the same property names. Thank you so much!